# Audio tag, add src when clicking on link?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a page with multiple `<audio>` tags in it and the page load takes forever (I have around 30 audio clips). A solution I saw was to leave the `src=""` empty and then dynamically populate when you click on a link...

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/

My snytax is wrong, but it has to do 2 things when the button is clicked. It has to load the video by populating the src and then playing the clip. I thought the following code would work:

```
document.getElementById('1')[0].src = '1.aif';.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements are executed separately, so `.play()` doesn't execute on the element. It's invalid, since a statement cannot start with `.`.

What you seem to want is "chaining style" (execute several things elegantly in one statement), which jQuery enables you to use:

```
$("#1").attr("src", "1.aif").play();
```

Or in pure JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('1'); // returns one element, not an array
elem.src = '1.aif';
elem.play();
```

Comment: I noticed that you can use the pure Javascript inline, but using the jQuery did not work (I even changed the " to ', and of course had jQ in the head). Is it not supposed to work?

Comment: @Charlie: Strictly speaking, `elem.src` is setting a property. Could you try `.prop` instead of `.attr`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problems are:

1. `getElementById` returns the element with the given **unique** identifier, not a NodeList (so `[0]` won't work because there isn't a `0` property)
2. Your second statement is trying to call `play` on nothing. You need something before the `.`

You probably want to just set [`preload="none"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html#attr-media-preload) instead of trying to dynamically set the `src`.

Comment: Since `<audio>` is HTML5, I think the HTML5 spec regarding IDs should be applied, in which IDs can start with a digit - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#concept-id.